# How to hide multiple dropdowns in navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have 3 dropdowns in my navigation.  When I hover on an item in the first dropdown the second dropdown shows which it should but the 3rd dropdown also shows.  I need it to only show when I hover over an item in the second dropdown.  I hope that all makes sense.  This is the url to the dev site - https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/.

This is my css -

```css
nav[role="navigation"] { position: relative; }

nav[role="navigation"] ul { margin: 0 0 0 0;
                            padding: 0 0 0 0; 
                            display: block; }

nav[role="navigation"] ul li { clear: both; display: inline-block; }
nav[role="navigation"] ul li a {  }

nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul  { display: none; } 
nav[role="navigation"] ul li:hover ul  { display: block; } 
nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul  { position: absolute;
                                   padding: 10px 0 0 0; }

nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul li { display: block;
                                     position: relative; }

nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul li ul  { 
    display: none !important; 
}
nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul li:hover ul  {  
    display: inline !important;
}
nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul li ul { 
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul li ul li {
        position: relative;
}

nav[role="navigation"] ul ul ul ul  { 
    display: none !important; 
}
nav[role="navigation"] ul ul ul li:hover ul  { display: inline !important; 
}
nav[role="navigation"] ul ul ul ul { padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;}

nav[role="navigation"] ul ul ul ul li { display: inline-block !important;
                                           position: relative; }

/* Top Navigation */

#access {
  padding: 28px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#access ul {
    text-align: right;
}         
#access a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
}
#access li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 0;
}
#access a:hover { 
    color: #DCA812; 
}
#access li.current-menu-item a {
    border-bottom: solid 4px #DCA812;
}
#access ul li ul {
    width: 300px;
}
#access ul li:hover ul  {
    background: #0B335B;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
#access ul li ul li ul {
    width: 200px;
    left: 290px;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul li ul li ul li {
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}
#access ul li ul li ul li ul {
    width: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul li ul li ul li ul li {
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}
```

So when I hover over Residences & Services in the main navigation the first dropdown shows.  In that dropdown when I hover over Providence Point the second dropdown shows along with the third dropdown.  I only want the third dropdown to show when you hover on Independent Living.

Residences & Services >
Providence Point >
Apartment Residences
Patio Homes

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [CSS child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). This will target the direct child of the element.

Your selector `li:hover ul` will apply styles to any `ul` nested inside `li` which is why the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns appear.

I added the `>` in between `li:hover` and `ul` in code below. This will ensure when hovering the `li`, it will display the first direct child `ul` and not the rest.

```css
nav[role="navigation"] ul li:hover > ul  { display: block; } 

nav[role="navigation"] ul li ul li:hover > ul  {  
    display: inline !important;
}

nav[role="navigation"] ul ul ul li:hover > ul  { display: inline !important;
```

Updated dropdown without width,

```css
body {background: teal;}

/* Top Navigation */

#access ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}

#access a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#access a:hover { 
  color: #DCA812; 
}

#access li.current-menu-item a {
  border-bottom: solid 4px #DCA812;
}

#access li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

#access li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  background: #0B335B;
}

#access ul ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

#access ul ul li {
  display: block;
}

#access ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <nav id="access" role="navigation" class="clearfix">
                    
                    
            <div class="menu-primary-container">
          <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
          
    <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-78"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/">Residences &amp; Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-126"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/">Providence Point</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-221" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-221"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/independent-living/">Independent Living</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-220" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-220"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/independent-living/apartment-residences/">Apartment Residences</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-223" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-223"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/independent-living/patio-homes/">Patio Homes</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
            <li id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-164"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/personal-care/">Personal Care</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/skilled-nursing-care/">Skilled Nursing Care and Rehabilitation</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-169"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/providence-point/memory-support/">Memory Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-219"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/hospice/">Hospice</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-242"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/health-wellness/">Health &amp; Wellness</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-240" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-240"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/health-wellness/events/">Events</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-239"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/health-wellness/wellness/">Wellness</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-241"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/health-wellness/dining/">Dining</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="menu-item-246" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-246"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/baptist-management-services/">Baptist Management Services</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-258"><a href="https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/residences-services/baptist-manor/">Baptist Manor</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    </ul></div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I have one more question.  Is there a way to set each dropdown width to automatically fit instead of setting a size and left position for each?

Comment: Updated post with quick solution without width but not great. You can try using flexbox on your `#access` to remove the hardcoded width and left position.